# Optional extension for any types

Tags: swift, generics, option-type, swift-extensions

I want to write `Optional` extension for *any* types.

**My code for integer:**

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Int {

    func ifNil<T>(default: T) -> T {
        if self != nil {
            return self as! T
        }
        return default
    }
}

var tempInt: Int?

tempInt.ifNil(default: 2) // returns 2

tempInt = 5

tempInt.ifNil(default: 2) // returns 5
```

It works but it is `Optional(Int)` extension (`Optional where Wrapped == Int`), I want to use this extension for ***any*** types like `Date`, `String`, `Double` etc.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: `isNil(value: 2)` really looks like it should be checking whether `2` is `nil`, and returning a `Bool`. A better method name should involve a term like `or`, `default`, `else`, like `unwrapped(orDefault: 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your basic question is to just remove the `where` clause:

```
extension Optional { 
    // ... the rest is the same 
    func isNil<T>(value: T) -> T {
        if self != nil {
            return self as! T
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Now it applies to all Optionals.

But this code is quite broken. It crashes if `T` is not the same as `Wrapped`. So you would really mean a non-generic function that works on `Wrapped`:

```
extension Optional {
    func isNil(value: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        if self != nil {
            return self!  // `as!` is unnecessary
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

But this is just an elaborate way of saying `??` (as matt points out)

```
extension Optional {
    func isNil(value: Wrapped) -> Wrapped { self ?? value }
}
```

Except that `??` is much more powerful. It includes an autoclosure that avoids evaluating the default value unless it's actually used, and which can `throw`. It's also much more idiomatic Swift in most cases. You can find the [source on github](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d6053dc5770c19a820b5e8d80248d226ae8a11e7/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L610-L618).

```
public func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T)
    rethrows -> T {
  switch optional {
  case .some(let value):
    return value
  case .none:
    return try defaultValue()
  }
}
```

But I can imagine cases where you might a method-based solution (they're weird, but maybe there are such cases). You can get that by just rewriting it as a method:

```
extension Optional {
    public func value(or defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> Wrapped) rethrows -> Wrapped {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            return value
        case .none:
            return try defaultValue()
        }
    }
}

tempInt.value(or: 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Optional is *already* a generic. It *already* takes any type as its parameterized type. Its parameterized already *has* a name: `Wrapped`. Just say `Wrapped` instead of `T`. Your `T` *is* `Wrapped`.

```
extension Optional {
    func isNil<Wrapped>(value: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        if self != nil {
            return self as! Wrapped
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

If you really prefer `T` for some reason, use a type alias. It's only a name:

```
extension Optional {
    typealias T = Wrapped
    func isNil<T>(value: T) -> T {
        if self != nil {
            return self as! T
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

But in any case your extension is completely unnecessary because this is what the nil-coalescing operator `??` already does.

```
var tempInt: Int?
tempInt ?? 2 /// returns 2
tempInt = 5
tempInt ?? 2 /// returns 5
```

Comment: There is an important (but I suspect accidental) difference. Because `<Wrapped>` is passed as a generic parameter to the function, `isNil(value: "")` will crash if `tempInt` is not nil. I think this is meant to be `isNil(...)`, not `isNil<Wrapped>(...)`

Comment: And of course should be implemented `func isNil(value: Wrapped) -> Wrapped { self ?? value }` (as you say :D)

Comment: Yes I see what you mean about the first part. But that fault is built into the OP's original code; my goal was not to improve the code but just to answer _the question_, which was how to "translate" the original code into something that applies no matter what the parameterized type is. The entire extension is badly written as well as unwise, there's no doubt of that.

Comment: Fair, though then I would *only* provide the `<T>` version. The `<Wrapped>` version is likely to be misleading to people, since it shadows the associated type, which I suspect many readers will not catch. (Saying "your `T` is `Wrapped`" sounds a lot like `T == Optional.Wrapped`, which isn't true.) Even in your second version, `T` does not equal `Optional.T`. The generic parameter shadows the typealias.